# Reading file from database gives error TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python

I am trying to read data from a table(which I have stored in a database). When I am trying to run the module its giving me the error "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()". Can anyone please help me ?

The code is as below :

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
c = conn.cursor()    
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

def read_from_db():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM DATA1')
    data = c.fetchall()
channel.queue_declare(queue = 'hello')
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key ='hello',
                      body = read_from_db())

print("[x] Sent 'Data'")
connection.close()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Also I have attached the image of table which I am trying to read.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AK4Z.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your `read_from_db` function doesn't explicitly return anything, so when you call it, the caller gets `None` as the result. You're passing that `None` value to some other library code where the exception presumably happens (it would be easier to be sure if you included the full traceback in the question).

Try adding `return data` to the end of your function. That way you won't be passing `None` around where you expect something else.